# Can the built-in OS X "Location" feature auto select locations based on wireless networks?

Tags: network, security

My home network is very secure, but my school's wireless network is open, which makes it vulnerable to wireless sniffing (e.g. with Firesheep). I just discovered the Location feature and I think it's really neat, but it doesn't make obvious a way to automatically switch Location based on which wireless network is currently connected.

Is this something which it is capable of, and if so then how do I set this up? Otherwise I guess I will use a program like NetworkLocation to do this; I'd just like to avoid paying for a program if possible.

(I'm using the latest Snow Leopard 10.6.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned Firesheep, let me put in a plug for [Sheepsafe](https://github.com/nicksieger/sheepsafe):

> Sheepsafe was built to automate the task of switching your network configuration to use a SOCKS proxy whenever you join an untrusted network.
>
> Sheepsafe works by keeping a configuration of known safe wireless networks. When you join an untrusted network, Sheepsafe switches to a network location that has a SOCKS proxy configured and starts a SOCKS proxy by SSH'ing into a remote server, thus protecting your browsing traffic from FireSheep and other snoopers on the local network. When you switch back to a safe network, Sheepsafe switches back to the default, trusted location and shuts down the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: I actually did eventually find this! Earlier this week I set up Sheepsafe and got it working. It connects to an Amazon EC2 server I set up (which will be free for a year, thanks to Amazon's free usage tier) and I'm rather happy with how it turned out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of location switch apps that work along with the Location feature such as NetworkLocation and LocationX. A more recent release you could also try is [Airport Location](http://airportlocationformac.com/)

Comment: The indicated web server doesn't seem to be the right one.
Something fallen from the wrong side of Google?.
Isn't this one the right location:
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34484/airport-location ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Location function` doesn't let you automatically switch to the
right network configuration.

You have to know that the original `Automatic` location configuration is a real security hole since it lets all you network interfaces up and doesn't give you a correct information of which one you are riding on.
You can always check by looking at `Apple > Location > Network Preferences...`

This `Automatic` configuration is also one of the nightmares of any network engineer.