# Change network location automatically based on network

Tags: network

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can the built-in OS X “Location” feature auto select locations based on wireless networks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/can-the-built-in-os-x-location-feature-auto-select-locations-based-on-wireless)
>   [Can I automate location changing so I don't have to drive the choice manually?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/can-i-automate-location-changing-so-i-dont-have-to-drive-the-choice-manually)
>   [Start/stop internet sharing from a script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script)

Is it possible in Mac OS X to somehow make it change the network location from a custom location profile to automatic when leaving the home network without having to manually adjust the settings in system preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Although not automatically, a shorter way to go is in the menu: apple->Location and then choose your location,.

Answer (score 0):

Airport Location** does that.

** Update 10/2016: Airport location appears to be no longer maintained, but still available at [MacUpdate.com](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34484/airport-location). It may be limited to older versions of OS-X. The same site suggests [ControlPlane](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39644/controlplane) provides similar functionality; I have not used it.

Comment: that link is broken